# Filter Collection using Mysql4 Model

Tags: collection, model, collection-filtering

**Block file**

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Modulename extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{


        public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'mymodule.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());                
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
            return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

}
```

**Model/Mysql4/Module/Collection.php**

```
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Mysql4_ModuleName_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{

    public function _construct(){

        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('module/model');

    }


    public function addCustomFilter($customerId)
    {

        $sortByCustomer = 'customer_id = ?';
        $sortByOrder = 'order_id DESC';
        $this->getSelect()->where($sortByCustomer, $customerId)->order(new Zend_Db_Expr($sortByOrder));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Model/Mysql4/Modulename.php**

```
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Mysql4_ModuleName extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{

    public function _construct(){    

        // Note that the id refers to the key field in your database table.
        $this->_init('module/model','id');
    }

}
```

My frontend .phtml file, I am using below code to call my custom collection

```
<?php
$customerId = 1;
$customerCollection =  $this->getCollection()->addCustomFilter($customerId);

?>


<?php if ($customerCollection->getSize()): ?>
    <div>
                <?php foreach ($customerCollection as $collection): ?>
                    <tr class="first odd">
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $collection->someData(); ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As far as I know, this will call the collection from custom DB table. The issue here is I have already specified the filter in my collection file, but it still not showing `filtered` results.

Or do I need to add my filter function in `Model/Mysql4/Modulename.php` file ?

It also throws an exception of `Unrecognized method 'getSize()`

Please Guide.

Thanks

Comment: in the `addCustomFilter` before the return statement log your query to see how it looks like `Mage::log($this->getSelect()->__toString(), null, 'query.log', true)` then check the `var/log/query.log` file

Comment: The query is fine and gives expected result. The filter function is called as well, but results are not as expected.

Comment: Before calling `$customerCollection =  $this->getCollection()->addCustomFilter($customerId);` do you do someting else with `$this->getCollection()`? Like loading it or looping through it? Show your full template file.

Comment: Question Updated.

Comment: Now that I see the template, I conclude is not enough to diagnose the problem. You should add the block that is rendered by the template also. If `getSize` is not recognized then most probably your collection object is not what you thing it is.

Comment: Marius, can I filter the collection from my block file ?

Comment: put you model and config.xml code ehere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem

```
$this->getCollection()->load();
```

You are loading the collection and later you apply a filter in the template.
Once you load the collection all filters and sort orders applied have no effect.
So you should apply the filter before calling `load` or before iterating through the collection.
In this case you should apply the filter in the block class.

As a general case, the templates should be used only to present data, so all data manipulation should be done in the block classes.

**[EDIT]**
Make your construct method look like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection();
    $customerId = 1;
    $collection->addCustomFilter($customerId);
    $this->setCollection($collection);
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how could I filter the collection considering my code example ? adding `addCustomFilter` in my block class, throws exception of undefined function.

Comment: @Jordan. See my edit.

Comment: Jorgon:are you created  Model/Modulename.php?

Comment: Yes Amit, its already there.

Comment: Marius, you are amazing. I missed and was unaware of the code `$this->getCollection()->load();`, which was causing the issue. Its perfect. But question is do we need to apply filter in block class every time or advisable to do it in template files too ?

Answer (score 1):

in Model/Mysql4/Modulename.php

```
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
```

Should be:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
```

How to create database module:http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Try This

```
$Collection=Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->addFieldToSelect('*')->setOrder('order_id',DESC);
```

**$collection give array of Record of customer Id**

for get one item try this

```
$Collection->getFirstItem();
```

**EDIT Code for**

```
public function addCustomFilter($customerId =null){
        $this->getSelect()->where("customer_id =?",$customerId) ->order('order_id ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC);
        reeturn $this;
        }
```

and used

```
Mage::getResourceModel('module/model_collection')
```

instead of

```
Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection()
```

Comment: Modulename is just for reference purpose. There is no convention issue here.

Comment: Pls see my updated question

Comment: is this function give one record for one customer??

Comment: I'm 99% sure that this is not a file naming issue. But the tutorial link is nice though.

Comment: yes.. it was  my mistake.but  Model/Mysql4/Modulename.php file inherit class is wrong

Comment: Amit, I too can filter and loop collection like this `$customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('module/model_collection')
                          ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customerId))
                          ->setOrder('order_id', 'DESC');`, but instead of doing this in my phtml file, I want to do the same in my Collection.php file.

Comment: public function addCustomFilter($customerId)
    {

       
        $this->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->setOrder('order_id',DESC);
    }